# How to save effects applied by QtGraphicalEffects in QML

Tags: qt, graphics, qml, qimage, contrast

I have a QML based app which shall provide basic image editing. I have implemented cropping, and now I would like to add the effects provided by `QtGraphicalEffects`. I have added the effects to the QML, and added corresponding sliders, so I can add the effects to my image, which works well.

However, my question is, how I would be able to save those effects back to the image file? The problem is, that I am scaling down the image to fit the screen dimensions, therefore, saving directly from the QML / javascript would result in a shrinked image.

For the cropping part I have solved this by doing the cropping in C++, and re-opening the original image unscaled, and applying the cropping to the original image.

Could I do something similar in QML? E.g. when a save button is pressed, render the original image again in original size (off-screen, so its not visible), apply the effect, then save it? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an unscaled `Image` that has `Item::visible: false`, render all of the effects, and then use `Item::grabToImage` on the resulting rendering to save the result.

You can use `Image::implicitWidth` and `Image::implicitHeight` to get the native height and width of the original `Image` (before scaling).

Comment: What dimensions/anchors should I use for the non-visible image?
Will the dimensions of the `Image` in QML affect the actual size of the rederend/saved image?

Comment: You will need to use the dimensions you want. `grabToImage` basically "screen captures" a rendering of the Item so it will need to match the actual dimensions you need.

Comment: I have added the invisible image, and an invisible `BrightnessContrast`, which fills the invisible image.
After calling `grabToImage` on the `BrightnessContrast`, I still end up with reduced image size in the saved image.
The problem is, I don't know the picture size beforehand. As per documenation of `Image`, when no size is given, it shall have the full unscaled size of the image. Yet when I save it back it gets scaled down. I tried supplying `hiddenImage.size` to the `grabToImage`, but it did not help.

Comment: Have you tried using Image::implicitWidth and Image::implicitHeight? Those should be the size of the actual source image.

Comment: Thanks, works now. I had a mistake in the code (I rendered the visible/scaled `BrightnessContrast`). If you add your comment as answer I can accept it.

Comment: Ok, I added that comment about implicitWidth and implicitHeight to this answer.